# How to save the response data return by Facebook in Java class using Spring MVC

Tags: java, javascript, facebook, spring-mvc

I am trying to save the user data which is return by the Facebook response.
I am using Facebook Javascript.Response is in JSon format and I want to parse it first and then save it in to my database using java.

```
<script>
  // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
    // app know the current login status of the person.
    // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
    // for FB.getLoginStatus().
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.

    /*   var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
      var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
      console.log("User id is" + uid);
      console.log(accessToken); */
      document.getElementById('accesstoken').value=response.authResponse.accessToken;
      console.log(response.authResponse.accessToken);
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    } else {
      // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
      // they are logged into this app or not.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into Facebook.';
    }
  }

  // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
  // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
  // code below.
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.2' // use version 2.2
  });

  // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call 
  // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
  // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
  // the callback you provide.  They can be:
  //
  // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
  // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
  // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
  //    your app or not.
  //
  // These three cases are handled in the callback function.

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
  function testAPI() {

     // window.location="http://localhost:8080/SpringMvcHibernateJavaBased/list";
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me',  function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      console.log(response);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
      document.getElementById('usernamefb').value=response.name;
      document.getElementById('userId').value=response.id;
      document.getElementById('emailfb').value=response.email;


    });

  }

  function checkLogoutState(){
      FB.logout(function(response) {
          FB.Auth.setAuthResponse(null, 'unknown');

        });
      };
      function checkData()
      {
          return $.ajax({


              })
          }

</script>
```

I am using Spring MVC approach fully JAVA based not using any xml files.
I have searched lot but didn't get any solution

Answer (score 0):

In "if (response.status === 'connected') {}" block you need to call another API of Facebook to fetch the user's details by passing user id and token and after receiving the data you can call your own controller through Ajax and save into DB if required.

Another solution can be, you may use "http://projects.spring.io/spring-social/" on server side itself.

Krish